# Is it possible to preload images on InfoWindowAdapter?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

Hi guys I did a custom InfoWindowAdapter on my map, and I have an custom image for every marker that I download every time with Picasso library (I choose this library because is really easy to use and cache system is integrated), but since it a bit slow I wanna load all images before the user push on every marker, because now to see the image I have to wait some seconds after I push on a marker.

Screenshot:
[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: around 10MB of pictures...about 50 pics... I'm doing an app with a definite number of places and with the Picasso Library I download them only the first time or when the cache has been cleaned

Comment: Place progressbar on top of the `ImageView` and hide it when photo is loaded.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski but, how can I know when the photo is loaded? All is "incapsulated" into library functions

Comment: `.into(ImageView);` has overloaded version with `Callback` param with `onSuccess()` and `onError()` methods.

Comment: mhhhh very interesting... I try :) At the moment, really thank you!!

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski ok, but in "onSuccess" I should refresh the infowindowadapter...how can I do ??

P.S.: The "onSuccess" work but I don't know what I have to write to "Refresh" the InfoWindowAdapter, when the progressbar end, I have to refresh the infowindow